# polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

Hi! I am currently working on some calc2 online homework problems and I am having difficulty with this problem. I was trying to use the polar coordinates (d,a)with the equation of the line thus being r=d*sec(theta-a). I tried solving for d by setting d equal to sqrt((-19)^2+(-6)^2) which then came out to be 137621/6907. I then tried solving for a by setting it equal to arctan(-6/-19) which came out to be 17.52556837. I then plugged everything into the equation of the line which i had as r=d*sec(theta-a) to get r= (137621/6907)sec(theta-17.52556837). Clearly my answer is wrong but I do not know why. If someone can help me solve this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Ahh... my eyes are burning!

Answer (score 1):

The line is

$$L:\;\; y=-\frac{19}6x-\frac{208}3$$

and passing to polar coordinates:

$$r\sin\theta=-\frac{19}6r\cos\theta-\frac{208}3\implies r=-\frac{416}{6\sin\theta+19\cos\theta}$$

Comment: webworks is not accepting this as the correct answer

Comment: My condolences for that webwork...whatever that is. You check my answer and try to follow it. Either I did some mistake or I didn't. If I did fix it, or at least find it, otherwise I did no mistake and that web..whatever is wrong.